# Salesforce experience cloud - Object page not displaying any object data

Tags: salesforce-communities

I am trying to build an object page for a custom object in LWR simplified enhanced template. But it is not rendering any object data on the page. I can't find the components to display object data as well. Object has 2 recordtypes and some custom fields. I have tried 2 options:

Object page in experience cloud
Also, using sitepage where URL parameters are supplied as properties
I made sure that guest user profile has access to the custom object.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks